# Is it possible to quickly export a .jpg and .png simultaneously in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, photoshop-scripting, actions

I work with product images for an online retail site. Each product image needs to have a .jpg copy and .png copy. Currently, I just export once as .jpg and then export again as .png. This is both time-consuming and I often forget one of the file types. Is it possible to have a quick export that creates both filetypes simultaneously?

I've read about batch processing and photoshop actions, but I can't seem to get them to work. I record this action: File > Export > Export As > "Select .jpg" > Export > "Set Filename & Location (Repeat for .png). This, however, doesn't seem to actually record any action.

I've also recorded: File > Save As > "Name File, Select Location, Format: .jpg" > Save (Repeat for .png). This works in that I can use it to simultaneously save as .jpg and .png, but it doesn't allow me to change the filename or location.

Comment: You could record an Action to do that. See [Creating Photoshop Actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html)

Comment: Batch processing means to run the same action for a range of files. That action could save png and jpg.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think you're on to something. I tried recording an action, but when I trigger it nothing happens. I record: File > Export > Export As > Select .jpg > Export > Set Filename and Location. It doesn't seem to record any of that.

Comment: Don't use Export As.  It's not recordable in Actions.  Use File > Save As instead.

Comment: @BillyKerr this action works as expected, but doesn't allow me to change the filename or location, it saves as the recorded name and location.

Comment: Yes. The file name will be the same as your PSD and in the same location, but the file extensions will be different - i.e. .PNG and .JPG - so you will end up with 3 files, the original PSD you saved, and the png and the jpeg

Comment: @BillyKerr If possible, how would I go about individually naming files? Also, thanks for opening my eyes to Photoshop actions, I've already created several 

Comment: I think you'd probably need to write a script of some kind. Sorry, I've very little experience with scripting.  But you may be able to work around this without scripting, if you have your original PSDs in a folder. Then the saved PNGs and JPEGs will end up in the same folder. Then you could rename the files manually, or move them to a different folder manually.  Yeah actions are fun, but they have limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research I was able to develop my first Photoshop script to do the trick. This script might be a little dirty (I'm new to JavaScript).

The script does the following:

1. Ask the User for a filename.
2. Ask the User to select a save folder.
3. Save as .jpg
4. Save as .png
5. Alert the User that the operation is completed.

```
// ASK FOR FILENAME
var filename = prompt("Type in Filename", "untiled").replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
// SELECT A SAVE LOCATION
var filepath = Folder.selectDialog("Choose a Save Location");


saveJPG(filename, filepath); // Run "Save as JPG" Function
savePNG(filename, filepath); // Run "Save as PNG" Function
alert("Complete"); // Alert the User that the Operation is Complete

// SAVE AS JPG
function saveJPG(filename, filepath) {
    var fileJPG = File(filepath + "/" + filename + ".jpg"); // Create .jpg file

    var jpgOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions;
    jpgOptions.quality = 9;
    jpgOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;

    // Save as .jpg
    activeDocument.saveAs(fileJPG, jpgOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
};

// SAVE AS PNG
function savePNG(filename, filepath) {
    var filePNG = File(filepath + "/" + filename + ".png"); // Create .png file

    var pngOptions = new PNGSaveOptions;
    pngOptions.compression = 9;

    // Save as .png
    activeDocument.saveAs(filePNG, pngOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
};
```

To get a keyboard shortcut to run the script, I simply recorded a Photoshop action.

Comment: Hi I have a question that can we modify to keep original filenames?

Comment: @Daniel, I've made [a similar script](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/b878d993b038b98b8ca78cc859916af4) that places the current doc name into the prompt: `app.activeDocument.name.split('.')[0]`. The primary file format is PSD and the secondary file format is JPEG, but with both of these scripts you should be able to modify either to fit your needs.